# jquery-ui : drop&drag inventory with stackable items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

**Hello everyone,**

I'm building a drop&drag inventory panel for my webgame, but I was unable to make it work with stackable elements. I have simplified the whole inventory so that it's less confusing.

**FIrst off, let me explain  how do I expect it to work:**

1. Every `.item` element can be dropped on any free `.inv_slot`.
2. If I try to drop an `.item` element on another `.item` that does not contain class `.stackable`, it will simply activate the draggable's `revert()` function.
3. if I try to drop the `.item` element on an `.item` that does have the `.stackable` class,
   it will only remove the clone/helper. *(Later on I will addd an function that only increases the items stack size.)*

**Now what's wrong with the below example :**

1. in case an `.item` accidentally dropped on border or between two `.inv_slot`slots, the Revert animation is not activated.  It does work however, while dropping the .item element outside the `#panel`.
2. Also if I accidentally dropped an `.item` between two `.inv_slot` elements,  it will behave as if the `.item` was dropped on a `.stackable` item. So it will remove the clone instead of reverting back to it's prev. position. (Most likely an issue with the selector in drop: method)
3. If I drop a `.stackable` item over another `.stackable` item, it does not refresh the cursor. It seems to be stuck in the drag mode which activates the "pointer" cursor.

**Now here's the (partialy working) example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 //var prev_el = '';
 var item_isStackable = "";
 
 $( ".item").draggable({
  scroll: true,
  revert: function(isValidEl)
  {
   if(isValidEl)
   {
    return false;
   }else{
    return true;
   }
  },
  helper: "clone",
  cursor: "pointer",
  stack: false,
  zIndex: 27,
  drag: function(event, ui)
  {
   item_isStackable = $(this).hasClass("stackable");
  },
 });
 $( ".inv_slot" ).droppable({
  accept: ".item",
  drop: function( event, ui ) { 
   var item = $(this).find(".item"); 
   if(item.length == 0) /// See if there any items already in the currently selected inventory slot  // 
   {
    console.log("Inserting");
    ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this)); // if none, insert the item into athe free slot /// 
   }
   else if(item_isStackable == true && item.hasClass("stackable")){
     console.log("Increasing "); 
     ui.draggable.detach(); /// If yes, just destroy the clone /// 
   }else{
    console.log("reverting back");
    // in case it's not .inv_slot , revert the item back to it's previous position //
    ui.draggable.animate(ui.draggable.data().origPosition,"slow");  
   }
  }
 });
});
```

```css
#panel
{
 width: 340px;
 height: 44px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 padding: 4px;
}

.inv_slot
{
 z-index: 22;
 position: relative;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 float: left;
}

.inv_slot .slot_pos{
 z-index: 24;
 position: absolute; 
 margin-left: 50%; 
 left: -4px; top: 2px;
}

.item
{
 position: relative;
 z-index: 25;
 margin: 4px;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 border: 1px solid blue;
}

.item.stackable
{
 border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="panel">
  <div class="inv_slot">
   <div class="item stackable" ></div>
   <span class="slot_pos">0</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="inv_slot">
   <div class="item"> </div>
   <span class="slot_pos">1</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="inv_slot">
   <div class="item stackable"> </div>
   <span class="slot_pos">2</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="inv_slot"><span class="slot_pos">3</span> </div>
  <div class="inv_slot"><span class="slot_pos">4</span> </div>
  <div class="inv_slot"><span class="slot_pos">5</span> </div>
  <div class="inv_slot"><span class="slot_pos">6</span> </div>
  <div class="inv_slot"><span class="slot_pos">7</span> </div>
</div>
```

I have spent couple of hours without any progress , so I'd really appreciate if someone could help me out with this one.

Thanks in advance,
Alex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that when you drag a box onto a border next to it, it deletes itself because it tries to stack itself. You need to change the second part of your `if` statement:

```
else if(item_isStackable == true && item.hasClass("stackable") && ui.draggable.filter(function() { var d = this; return item.filter(function() { return d == this; }).length > 0; }).length === 0)
```

To fix the cursor pointer problem:

```
.item
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 25;
    margin: 4px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    cursor: default !important; /* Add this property. */
}
```

**[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rczbq6a9/)**

Comment: I think you're right, it's now working as expected, except for the part where it should activate the revert animation.

Comment: Also the issue with stuck "pointer" cursor still remains.. try to drop the green box on another green box an see what happens..

Comment: I've been trying to fix the animation, but haven't had much luck. Maybe someone else will be able to provide a better answer. It doesn't seem to revert back on itself, probably because it is being dropped back into the same droppable.

Comment: Just tested your solution and after dropping the stockable item on another of same tyoe, the cursor was reset to default, but if I then tried to hover over any `.inv_slot` element an incorrect cursor was  displayed.  .. Any ideas?

Comment: the best way to solve this issue is to overwrite the cursor type for *body* element. 
I have added this to the drop method 
`ui.draggable.remove(); 
     $('body').css('cursor', 'auto');` and removed this line `ui.draggable.detach();`